# Cannot overwrite object attributes within associated object

Tags: python, associations, relation

I'm having a controller class that has some attributes. The attributes in this class might sometimes have to be overwritten with the values stored in a database. Unfortunately, I came across an issue that addresses a pretty fundamental thing in OOP I guess so I would really like to understand what I'am doing wrong instead writing an workaround.

My real code is of course much bigger but the next simplification should really show the problem.

```
class Project():
    def __init__(self):
        self.beams = 10

class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
         self.project = Project()

    def proc(self):
        self.r = Register(self.project)
        self.r.load()

class Register():
    def __init__(self, project):
         self.project = project

    def load(self):
        p2 = Project()
        p2.beams = 5

        self.project = p2
        # self.project.beams = 4

c = Controller()
print(c.project.beams)

c.proc()
c.r.load()

print(c.project.beams)
```

Expected results:

```
10
5
```

What I'm getting:

```
10
10
```

Note that when I use the commented line `self.project.beams = 4` line, the results are:

```
10
4
```

Apparently, I cannot overwrite the `project` attribute in the register class, but why not?

Comment: in the load method, why not do `self.project = Project()
        self.project.beams = 5`

Comment: Because in the real code, the project is a (un)pickled state of an object that has to replace the attribute in the controller. This is just a simplification causing the same problem as I'm having in the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is the project instance in your controller class is not changing when you pass it to the Register class but the project in Register class has changed and this change is not getting traversed to the Controller class and the way around it would be doing something like this

```
class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
         self.project = Project()

    def proc(self):
        self.r = Register(self.project)
        self.r.load()
        self.project = self.r.project
```

This is giving me the desired output, I don't know any other requirements but this is how I'd go forward with this.

Comment: I have to define the relationship between the two classes inside both classes.